# Spray: factor out onSuccess directive

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json, spray-dsl

I would like to change the following code fragment in a way that I want to factor out the onSuccess block into a new method. JSON marshalling should still work.

```
(patch & parameterMap & asJson) { params =>
   ...
   val f:Future[ResposeData]=createResponse(...)
   onSuccess(f){complete(_)}
}
```

I would like to have a method like:

```
def handleSuccess(f:Future/FutureMagnet)(implicit ...)
```

A simple refactoring doesn't work for me. I tried a lot of combinations but I can't find either the correct signature or the code working.

Example:

```
def handleSuccess(f: Future[ResposeData]): Unit = {
    onSuccess(f) { complete(_) }
}

Error:(43, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[ResponseData]
 required: spray.routing.directives.OnSuccessFutureMagnet
    onSuccess(f) {
          ^
```

If I now change signature I get another error:

```
def handleSuccess(f: OnSuccessFutureMagnet)

Error:(44, 18) spray.routing.Directive[f.Out] does not take parameters
    onSuccess(f) {
                 ^
```

Maybe this is just a simple thing to do but I'm new to spray.
So it would be nice if somebody could give a hint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onSuccess` takes a function, basically when you use that on your future the value inside the future becomes available and you can complete your route using that value if you want:

```
case class ResponseData(data: String)

def handleSuccess(f: Future[ResponseData]): Unit = {
  onSuccess(f) { responseData =>
    complete(_)
  }
}
```

From the comments:

> "Unwraps" a `Future[T]` and runs its inner route after future completion with the future's value as an extraction of type `T`.

Note also that

> If the future fails its failure throwable is bubbled up to the nearest ExceptionHandler.

Maybe you want to use `onComplete` which returns a `Try` and you can then match on `Success` or `Failure`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. No problem to factor out onComplete. It looks as expected `def handleResult[T:ToResponseMarshaller](f:OnCompleteFutureMagnet[T])`. But I'm still wonder what the problem with onSuccess is.

Comment: @Fred4242 sorry I was on vacation, the problem is that `onSuccess` 'unwraps' the future for you, so if you have a `Future[T]`, `onSuccess` takes that future as first parameter and then a function from `T` to a `Route`, the difference between your code and mine is that yours just pasts in a `Route` (`{ complete(_) }` ) as second parameter and not a function `T => Route` (`{ responseData => complete(_) }`)